# Python Django 'TypeError: object is not iterable' when trying to iterate over models query set

Tags: django, django-models

All, I've read through previous posts of similar issues and none seem to solve my problem.

I'm making a website for my fantasy football league as my intro to Django. However, I'm running into an error every time I try to insert content from my models into the HTML template. The error shown is **'TypeError: 'PastSeasons' object is not iterable'**, with 'PastSeasons' being the model.

I know the PostgreSQL table and DB is set up properly because I can view it via pgadmin4 and through the Django /admin site. I can also run the 'python manage.py shell' and query the model, return a queryset, and then iterate through that queryset using the exact same syntax as the views.py file.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class PastSeasons(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    place = models.IntegerField()
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    wins = models.IntegerField()
    losses = models.IntegerField()
    ties = models.IntegerField()
    points_for = models.FloatField()
    points_against = models.FloatField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.year)
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import PastSeasons

def past(request):
    past_list = PastSeasons.objects.all()
    past_szn = {'past_szn': past_list}
    return render(request, 'basic_app/past_seasons.html', past_szn)
```

**HTML template** (there's additional column headers and styling elements which I'm leaving out to be concise):

```
{% if past_szn %}
{% for i in past_szn %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{ i.year }}</th>
              <td>{{ i.place }}</td>
              <td>{{i.owner}}</td>
              <td>{{i.wins}}</td>
              <td>{{i.losses}}</td>
              <td>{{i.ties}}</td>
              <td>{{i.points_for}}</td>
              <td>{{i.points_against}}</td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the exact code? It looks like you did something like `PastSeasons.object.get(...)` instead of `.all(..)`.

Comment: I've tried both `PastSeasons.objects.order_by('year')` and `PastSeasons.objects.all()` with the same results. Both still return the entire table queryset if run from the shell, and both give a `TypeError: PastSeasons object is not iterable` when running the django application locally and accessing the page.

Comment: Is there another `{% for ... %}` in your template?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct and as @WillemVanOnsem said, it could something else in your html template which is causing the error. Please show the entire html template.

Comment: Welp, I got it working. There was actually another `{%for ..%}` loop in my template that I had commented out as I was previous pulling from an API and iterating through a list of lists rather than the DB/models. This took way to long to load so I moved everything to a DB. I assumed because it was commented out that it wouldn't affect anything, but it appears I was wrong. Lesson learned. Thanks for the help.